# Simple Xml Framework loose mapping not working

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization, simple-framework

I am trying to parse part of an xml document using Simple Xml Framework with the loose mapping flag set but i get an exception.

XML:

```
<Body>
    <TopGoalScorersResponse>
        <TopGoalScorersResult>
            <tTopGoalScorer>
                <sName>Alan Dzagoev</sName>
                <iGoals>3</iGoals>
                <sCountry>Y</sCountry>
                <sFlag>http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/images/flags/ru.gif</sFlag>
                <sFlagLarge>http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/images/flags/ru.png</sFlagLarge>
            </tTopGoalScorer>
        </TopGoalScorersResult>
    </TopGoalScorersResponse>
</Body>
```

Java:

```
TopGoalScorer topGoalScorer = serializer.read(TopGoalScorer.class, xml);

@Root(name="tTopGoalScorer", strict=false)
public class TopGoalScorer {
    @Element(name="sName")
    private String name;

    @Element(name="iGoals")
    private int numGoals;

    @Element(name="sCountry")
    private String country;

    @Element(name="sFlag")
    private String flagImageUrl;
}
```

Exception:

```
06-22 14:11:46.530: E/Soap(2057): Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(data=false, name=sCountry,     required=true, type=void) on field 'country' private java.lang.String uk.co.carr.david.TopGoalScorer.country for class uk.co.carr.david.TopGoalScorer at line 1
06-22 14:11:46.530: E/Soap(2057): org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(data=false, name=sCountry, required=true, type=void) on field 'country' private java.lang.String uk.co.carr.david.TopGoalScorer.country for class uk.co.carr.david.TopGoalScorer at line 1
```

Any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because you didn't clarify path to the element, Just try to use next constructions and all will be OK

```
    @Root(name="tTopGoalScorer", strict=false)
    public class TopGoalScorer {
        @Path("Body/TopGoalScorersResponse/TopGoalScorersResult/tTopGoalScorer/sName")
        @Element
        private String name;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. I thought the idea of loose mapping was that you don't have to worry about all the surrounding xml? You can just focus on the portion of the xml you're interested in. This approach means you have to specify the exact path to each node, which isn't really much better than mirroring the whole xml document in java classes.

Comment: Try to read simple xml tutorial, but I've answered to your question

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this is Persister.read(MyClass.class, inputXml, false). This tells it to ignore anything not matched in the annotated class. Its better than using strict=false in the @Root annotation as it applies to the whole document.